# Distribution in the combinatorial optimization

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, extremal-combinatorics

There is a set **A** containing $N$ elements. Then we randomly choose $M$ out of $N (N≥M)$ elements to form a subset **B** and get the objective function $f(B)$. Different $B$ may lead to different $f(B)$.

My question is how can we get the distribution of $f(B)$? Or is there any paper discussing the relation or the gap between the average value $E[f(B)]$ of $f(B)$  and the optimal value OPT[$f(B)$] of $f(B)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is this different from your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184981/distribution-of-the-knapsack-problem)?

Comment: In the previous question, I described it by using the knapsack problem. Then I found it was not clear and even mislead readers. In the previous description, as you mentioned, the optimal is obviously picking the M highest cost items out of N items. In that case $p(a)+p(b)=p(a+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are two items. Here, I use the concept of the combinatorial optimization to say that $p(a)+p(b)!=p(a+b)$ . The optimal f(B) is not equal to the sum of f(i) where i is any element in B.

Comment: oh i see...  but if you don't tell us anything about $f()$ as a function, how can we say anything about $E[f(B)]$ and $\max_B f(B)$?